# Is it safe to assume that the initializer URLComponents(url:resolvingAgainstBaseURL:) never returns nil?

Tags: swift, url, nsurl, foundation

When you have a `URL` in Swift and want to create a `URLComponents` instance from it, you have to use this initializer:

```
init?(url: URL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: Bool)
```

I never understood why this initializer is failable. The initializer `URL(string:)` is already failable and returns `nil` if the `string` does not represent a valid URL. Therefore, I would assume that a `URL` (once successfully created) is always valid. Consequently, it should be possible to always construct a `URLComponents` instance from any given URL.

However, if this assumption was true, the above initializer wouldn't need to be failable. Why is it and under which circumstances is it guaranteed to succeed and return a non-nil value?

Comment: It would seem, based on info in the duplicate, that if an app is linked with a Base SDK of iOS 17 or later, this `URLComponents` initializer can't return `nil`. But for apps still linked to older versions of iOS, it's possible to have a "valid" `URL` instance that doesn't lead to a valid `URLComponents` instance. Though even under iOS 17, there might be issues if you decode a `URL` instance that was encoded with older versions of the app built before iOS 17.